# What is a good framework for creating interactive books on the iPad?

Tags: ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I was wondering if anyone knew the best way to create interactive books for the iPad (such as the Alice in Wonderland and Dr. Seuss books currently available in the App Store)? I am looking at using Cocos2D which seems like it could be a good option. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Tim. have you finished your this app ? I would like to know more about this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cocos2d is definitely doable, have a look [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120211001713/http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/11197).  You could also use core animation depending on how interactive you want the book to be.

Comment: I think your link has been redirected.

Comment: Thanks, updated to an archive.org link.

Answer (score 3):

If you want an intermediate solution (i.e. more than epub but less than cocos2d), try http://bakerframework.com/  It is an HTML5 ebook framework. The "book" portion is developed in HTML5 and the project includes an XCode app to compile the HTML5 into an app that manages page turns, etc.  Project is BSD license.