# Creating an Interactive Book for iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I already seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385709/what-is-a-good-framework-for-creating-interactive-books-on-the-ipad) question, but since its a bit outdated, I was wondering if there are better frameworks/tools to achieve it in the current days. As the same user pointed out, I am looking for the same kind of interaction that you might see in  Alice in Wonderland and Dr. Seuss books. So:

- Is it Cocos2D still the best option all around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numberlys (recent and successful interactive book) was made with Cocos2D.  That doesn't mean that Cocos2D is the best option, even if there is such a thing, but it does mean that before they started, Moonbot surveyed the same landscape as me and you, and chose it over other options.

Comment: I am not saying Cocos2D is the best option... But for instance, Alice was created with it.

Comment: Yeah Danyal, I think too (from my own research) that it is the best option. If nothing else shows up, I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Latest tool from Apple itself - [iBooks Author](http://www.apple.com/ibooks-author/)

Don't now how exactly one should start with it but it's worthy giving a chance, I guess.

Comment: Nice stuff, but I think its too limited for the kind of animations Alice has.

Answer (score 1):

You can also go with Adobe's digital publishing tools http://www.adobe.com/solutions/digital-publishing.html

http://blogs.adobe.com/digitalpublishing/2010/07/introducing_the_adobe_digital_magazine_workflow.html

Comment: The point here is more about the relation between the user and the animations and not so much about the text. But thanks anyway.